# How to assign selected Items to a category, e.g. "beverages" or "UML" in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, hive, categories

User can make inputs as words in this app , and then create a category and assign it to it.But i don't know how it is possible to assign.
I can now select inputs by ListTile .

```
Container(
                 color: (_selectedItems.contains(index)) ? Colors.blue.withOpacity(0.5) : Colors.transparent,
                 //select and import to a category
                 child: ListTile(
                    onTap: (){
                    if(_selectedItems.contains(index)){
                    setState(() {
                    _selectedItems.removeWhere((val) => val == index);
                    });
                    }
                    },
                    onLongPress: (){
                    if(! _selectedItems.contains(index)){
                    setState(() {
                    _selectedItems.add(index);
                    });
                    }
                    },
                    title: _showWords(index),
              ),
              );
```

[image: here i can see all categories]

[image: when i clicked a category, then i can open a list of items(user's inputs):]

[image: here i can select items , but how can i import it to the category?]

Answer (score 0):

Create a class Category with int id, String name, List words e.t.c. (category id must be assign automatically when the user creates an instance of that category, when the user taps the category, save the choosen category id, then when the user wants to add a word, just add a word to the "words" parameter.